# Adding space BETWEEN cells in TableCell()

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code is below. I want to add space between cells in tableCell()
something the equivalent of

```
<td></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<td></td>
```

I am NOT looking for cellpadding or cellspacing because they both add space between the left cell border and the left table border (wall); I want to add space between two CELLS, not the table and the cell;

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Table tb = new Table();
    tb.ID = "tb1";

    for (int i = 0; i < iCounter; i++)
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        TextBox tbox = new TextBox();
        tbox.ID = i.ToString();

        TableCell tc = new TableCell();
        tc.Controls.Add(tbox);
        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
        tb.Rows.Add(tr);
    }
    pnlScheduler.Controls.Add(tb);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: it sounds like you're looking for exactly cellspacing...

Comment: but cellspacing adds space between the left border of the left cell and the left table. I dont want that;

Comment: see my answer below--try adding a "sub" table with the cell spacing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative might be this (I modified your code and added a label, which you can add alternate to every "tc.Controls.Add(tbox);"

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    Table tb = new Table(); 
    tb.ID = "tb1"; 

    for (int i = 0; i < iCounter; i++) 
    { 
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(); 
        TextBox tbox = new TextBox(); 
        TextBox tLabel = new Label();
        tbox.ID = i.ToString(); 

    tLabel.width = 10;

        TableCell tc = new TableCell(); 
        tc.Controls.Add(tbox);
    tc.Controls.Add(tLabel);
        tc.Controls.Add(tbox);
    tc.Controls.Add(tLabel);
        tc.Controls.Add(tbox);
    tc.Controls.Add(tLabel);
        tr.Cells.Add(tc); 
        tb.Rows.Add(tr); 
    } 
    pnlScheduler.Controls.Add(tb); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 TableCell tc = new TableCell();
    HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    div.Style.Add("padding-left", "5px");
    div.Style.Add("padding-right", "5px");

    div.Controls.Add(tbox);

    tc.Controls.Add(div);
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    tb.Rows.Add(tr);
```

Comment: the code you provided, adds padding between the cell and the table. Not what I am looking for;

Comment: Sorry you are right, I already edit post with the right answer, please check it out

Answer (score 1):

*edit

My apologies for the margin, I don't think it is possible with margins, however I was able to create a css that can be applied to the middle cells give them padding on both the left and right sides.

but to get around the fact that the first and last elements don't push out against the wall of the table you have to apply the class to only the middle td's

example of css code

```
table
{
border:1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
table-layout: fixed;
}
td.middle
{
border:1px solid black;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
}
```

and then your middle td's would be created with the `<td class="middle"></td>`

however to convert this type of code to c# I'm not entirely sure. I will keep looking on how to apply this class to only specific elements, but your best bet would be to create a flag that checks the element to make sure that they aren't the first or last ones in the table, unless you are adding them manually then you just add the class manually as needed.

However might I suggest that if this is for page layout, your better off having css do the work for you instead of using table design. But if it's to show data in a table format then never mind, I said nothing.

Hope this helps. will post if I find anything else.

Comment: can you provide a sample syntax that I can use in codebehind block?

Comment: @user279521 sorry for the long reply, was out for lunch. If you go to http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_reference.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_margin-left.asp they explain the different elements that a table has. also http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html gives you a comprehensive look at table design. I will post a code as an example soon.

Answer (score 0):

you could always add "empty" cells of the desired with.

Answer (score 0):

For giving space between the table cells we have to use table's cellpadding and cellspacing property.

<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
</table>

<TABLE CELLSPACING="X">

The X in the line, is replaced with the number of pixels you want between the cells.

<TABLE CELLPADDING="X">

The X in the line, is replaced with the number of pixels you want between the text and cell edge.

Answer (score 0):

When you're ready to add two cells with this spacing, create a table instead; with one row and two td's like:

```
<table cellspacing="2"><tr><td>stuff</td><td>more stuff></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: can you convert this into the codebehind syntax like I have my sample code? The issue is I can't seem to add html script to my tc.Controls.Add(tbox); syntax

Answer (score 0):

Apply a left margin to the table's td (except the last one in each row). 
You can do it by assigning a common class, or by applying a class that reset the margin only to the last td.

You can use jQuery either and inject margin, but doing it via css only is cleaner.